# Lisp method process

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Can you help me? I don't understand this code's part

```
(lambda (this &rest args) ;; Adds The THIS Argument
  (apply (get-slot this 
           method-name)
     (append (list this)
         args))))
```

Rewrite Method

```
;;;; This Function Add The Argument This To The Method
(defun rewrite-method (method-spec)
   (list 'lambda (append (list 'this) ;; Add The THIS Argument
               (second method-spec))
    (cons 'progn (rest (rest method-spec))))) ;; Eval All The Method's Body




;;;; Method-Process
;;;; Function Used To Process Methods, Rewriting Them To
;;;; Lisp Functions 
(defun method-process (method-name method-spec)
  (setf (fdefinition method-name) ;; Associate The Lambda To The Method's Name
    (lambda (this &rest args) ;; Adds The THIS Argument
      (apply (get-slot this 
               method-name)
         (append (list this)
             args))))   
  (eval (rewrite-method method-spec))) ;; Returned Value
```

Comment: It would be nice it you could format the code. It's impossible to read it.

Comment: https://github.com/sapo93/OOL/blob/master/ool.lisp

Answer (score 3):

It takes an arglist `(foo bar baz)` and adds a `this` parameter: `(this foo bar baz)`.

Thus a function `(lambda (foo bar baz) ...)` then is `(lambda (this foo bar baz) ...)`.

This is useful in implementation of single-inheritance object-oriented languages where the first argument is the object which receives a message and other arguments. Here the parameter `this` is the receiving object.

Note that the call to `APPLY` could be improved. `(apply function (append (list this) args))` is just `(apply function this args)`.